# Intermittent communication problems between Silverlight client and WCF service

Tags: silverlight, wcf, iis, silverlight-4.0, iis-7.5

I have a Silverlight 4 application that communicates with a server running IIS 7.5 that hosts a number of my own WCF services.  The application runs happily 99% of the time but users reports that a few times a day the application will freeze or error messages will be generated at various points in the application.

I turned on WCF tracing and the following errors occur:

```
<Exception>
  <ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
  <Message>The number of bytes available is inconsistent with the HTTP Content-Length header.  There may have been a network error or the client may be sending invalid requests.        </Message>
  <StackTrace>
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadBufferedMessage(Stream inputStream)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(Exception&amp; requestException)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action callback)
    at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
    at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
    at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
    at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
    at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
    at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
    at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
  </StackTrace>
</Exception>
```

I then ran Fiddler on a user's machine and found the following errors were occurring:

```
HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Timestamp: 18:24:21.941

ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.
```

From some research it looks like there is some communication problem between the client and the server.  The server is a Virtual Private server which I have never had any trouble with and from looking at the logs it is never maxed out processor/memory wise.

My questions are:
1.  Is there anything I can do to track what is happening in more detail or anything IIS or server related I can adjust to avoid this error
2.  In my Silverlight application is there some way I can wait a specific amount of time (e.g. 30 seconds) and if no response has been recieved cancel the current request and try again

Comment: Do you checked, if your service method throws an exception?

Comment: Jehof - the service method does not throw an exception.  You can make the exact same service method call after the error and it will work.

Comment: Do you checked, the event log of the server?

Comment: There are no errors in the event log.

Comment: @GaryJoynes - did you ever find out the issue, and how did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

A similar question is solved in the following webpage:
[Error at WCF Service The number of bytes available is inconsistent with the HTTP Content-Length header](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/1c520a22-f05a-406f-936d-bcb093383dec)